# phpMyAdmin not loading correctly

Tags: apache2, mysql, lamp, phpmyadmin

I have made a fresh install of Ubuntu Mate 16.10. I'm setting up a LAMP server for local testing (not serving to the internet).

Everything about the Apache and MySQL setup, using Synaptic, and the configuration settings I carried over from previous experience, all seemed to go ahead without a problem. But, after installing phpMyAdmin, when I load it up, I see what looks like the backend code:

[image: broken phpMyadmin]

How do I repair this and get phpMyAdmin to load properly?

Comment: Did you install PHP?

Comment: @bc2946088, I believe so. It's marked as installed in Synaptic.

Comment: what about... libapache2-mod-php7.0 ?

Comment: @bc2946088, that module wasn't installed. I installed it, and now phpMyAdmin works. Thank you. If you put that as an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are seeing PHP source, it would indicate php is most likely the culprit, however it could be the apache configuration as well.

First verify if PHP is installed `which php`, if this returns, we'll make the assumption the package is installed.

Next try to install, `sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.0`.  After installation it should automatically enable the module in Apache and restart.  If not, `sudo a2enmod php7.0` and test your page again.